# Wireframe visible through OpenGL drawn cubes, any ideas?

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, xamarin.ios, opentk

I'm a newbie to OpenGL/ES and OpenTK, so forgive me if my understanding/terminology is a little off.

Basically,

1. I'm drawing a series of [white] triangle-based-cubes using a Vertex Buffer Object Array (VBO's).
2. I then use the same vertices to render a [black] wireframe for the cubes, using lines & polygonOffset().
3. Problem is, I can see the wireframes that are rendered on the back-faces (i.e. see through), I'm unsure why (?).
4. I'm using 4-value colours (rgba), nothing I do to the 4th value (alpha/opacity) seems to do anything.

I ***have*** defined normals for the triangle-based cube sections, a total of 36 (2 x 3 verts/tri x 6 sides), however, I ***haven't*** defined any normals for the wireframe line segments (at present).

**Does anyone have any idea of what I might be doing wrong, solely based on OpenGL pitfalls/experience.**

JFYI, I'm using OpenTK-OpenGL ES11 on mono/monotouch (C#)

P.S. If you're wondering why I haven't posted any code, that is because the rendering code is mixed with game logic and spread across multiple files. I'll try to make a simple, self contained example as soon as I can, if necessary.

Comment: What are the values you are passing to glPolygonOffset, and on which draw calls? Have you glEnable( GL_POLYGON_OFFSET )?

Comment: @ryanm, I've got the following calls GL.EnableClientState(All.PolygonOffsetFill); GL.PolygonOffset(-0.1f, -0.1f); just before my cube redraw routine (but *not* the wireframe draw), followed by the corresponding disabling of the All.PolygonOffsetFill, does that look right?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have depth testing turned on. Even the fragments composing lines and points get depth tested, so if you have shapes drawn in front of lines, the shapes should occlude the lines.

You want to look at the `glEnable` function with parameter `GL_DEPTH_TEST`.

Comment: The following three lines are already defined in my EAGLView.CreateFrameBuffer() method:- GL.ClearDepth (1f); GL.Enable (All.DepthTest); GL.DepthFunc (All.Lequal);. The order of these came about via copy & paste (sorry), so I'm unsure as to whether they're correct. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that GL.EnableClientState is a direct analog of [glEnableClientState](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/1.1/docs/man/glEnableClientState.xml), this is not how polygon offset is enabled. Is there an equivalent of [glEnable](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/1.1/docs/man/glEnable.xml)?
The following works for me to get a visible wireframe:

```
 glEnable( GL_POLYGON_OFFSET_FILL );
 // push back the filled faces a touch
 glPolygonOffset( 1, 1 );
 // draw filled faces
 ...
 glDisable( GL_POLYGON_OFFSET_FILL );
 // draw wireframe
 ...
```

Comment: thanks for replying so quickly ;-) . Your code fragment outlines the order I'm doing things and, yes, OpenTK's GL class (here ES11.GL) *does* have an equivalent GL.Enable method (see http://www.opentk.com/files/doc/functions_0x65.html#index_e). I'm at work now, so I don't have my Mac, but I'll try to verify this change later today. Thanks again ;-)